# To which group is $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to see to which group $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to. I have shown that the order of the group is $4$ and so it must be isomorphic either to the klein group or the cyclic group of order $4$ but I am not sure how to see which one it is?

Comment: By the usual Galois correspondence the subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(i+\sqrt{2})$ are in bijection with the subgroups of the Galois group. Since the two possibilities have different numbers of subgroups you can just start listing subfields until you have ruled out one of the two ...

Comment: Can you tell what the elements of the Galois group are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can immediately see two intermediate fields, namely $\mathbb Q(i)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ (Of course there is a third, but who cares...). Thus the galois group has at least two subgroups of order two. Hence it cannot be cyclic. The correct answer is the klein group.

Comment: It does require some minor calculation to show that $i, \sqrt2\in \Bbb Q(i + \sqrt 2)$ (see the other answer), but once you've done that, you're good to go.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, but it is pretty standard and the OP implicitly claims that he has checked that the extension is normal (Because he has checked that the group has four elements). The fact that $i,\sqrt{2}$ are contained in the field should fall off from a computation that shows normality.

Answer (score 3):

Klein four group has a property that $\forall v\in\textbf{V}, v*v=e$, it's easy to check that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q})$ satisfies this condition for sure.

Answer (score 2):

An idea for you to mull (fill in details): since

$$(\sqrt2+i)(\sqrt2-i)=3\implies\sqrt2-i=\frac3{\sqrt2+i}\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+i)$$

and thus also

$$(\sqrt2+i)+(\sqrt2-i)=2\sqrt2\implies \sqrt2\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt2+i)$$

and likewise $\;i\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+i)\;$ , so $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,i)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2+i)\;$ (details)...