# Prove $Aut(M)$ is isomorphic to $V_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-representations

The full question is as follows:
Take $M=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ and $\alpha=1+i+\sqrt{2}$. Prove that $G=Aut(M)$ is isomorphic to $V_4$, where $V_4$ is the group of order 4 not cyclic (Klein group).

I’ve seen a few examples of this type of problem. I understand the method is to first prove that $G$ has order 4, and then that none of its elements generate the group (hence it’s not cyclic and therefore it is isomorphic to $V_4$.

What gets me in trouble is proving it has degree 4, since I am not allowed to use advanced results of Galois theory, only some theorems about field extensions.

Second part of the problem says: Prove that $f=\Pi_{\sigma\in G} (X-\sigma(\alpha))$ is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Some ideas on how to attack this problem?

Comment: Well, probably you know that $[M:K]=[M:L][L:K]$ for a tower of extensions, and for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ it should be pretty easy to prove that all extensions are of degree $2$.

Comment: And $G$ is not cyclic because [it has at least 2 elements of order 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2291814/386889): the automorphism which fixes $\sqrt2$ and sends $i$ to $-i,$ and the automorphism which fixes $i$ and sends $\sqrt2$ to $-\sqrt2.$

Comment: I can see the proof of $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$. But now, how do you prove the order of $G=Aut(M)$ is also 4?

Comment: An element of $G$ can only send $i$ to $\pm i$ and $\sqrt2$ to $\pm\sqrt2.$

Comment: Are you sure, that $[K:\Bbb Q]=|{\rm Aut}(G)|$ was not proved before the exercise in the text, for a finite Galois extension? This is not an "advanced" result of Galois theory. In which book did you find this exercise?